# Trace embedding and unbounded domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open domain and let consider the open cylinder $D\times (0,T)\subset\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ where $T\in (0,+\infty)$ arbitrary. Let $H^{1}(D\times (0,T))$ be the Sobolev space defined as usual. 
It is known that: if we assume that $D$ satisfies the cone condition, then we have 
the continuous embeding 
$$H^{1}(D\times (0,T))\mapsto L^{2}(D\times \{\tau=t \})$$
for every $t\in (0,T)$ (see the book of Adams).

My question is:
If $D$ is an unbounded domain with finite volume and it hasn't the cone condition,does the above embedding still true? and under which assypmtions?
 Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the continuous embedding"? Shouldn't it be a well-defined version of $f \mapsto f(\cdot,t)$? This is never injective and hence, I would not call this an *embedding*.

Comment: It means that: $||f(.,t)||_{L^{2}(D)}\leq k ||f||_{H^{1}(D)}$ with $K$ is a constant

Comment: Hence, for every $t\in (0,T)$,  we get $x\mapsto f(x,t) \in L^{2}(D) ,$ what I need.